# Migrations in EF Core RC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

When I try to add migration I get:

> This preview of Entity Framework tools does not support targeting class library projects in ASP.NET Core and .NET Core applications. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for details and workarounds.

But in my `project.json` file I have this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
       "buildOptions": {
          "emitEntryPoint": true
       }
    }
}
```

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally y put out this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
    }
},
"buildOptions": {
          "emitEntryPoint": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put in your project.json and create a Program.cs File

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had converted my library containing my data models to using the "netcoreapp1.0" framework instead of "netstandard1.5", this includes including the Microsoft.NETCore.App dependency and build options, and requiring the hosting core right now.

I had *just* run into this (first time tweaking migrations since RC2 conversion) and I'm not finding better options for now. I'll continue digging but if you're stalled this configuration appears to get me back running for now.

Comment: could you elaborate what "requiring the hosting core" means? Because I'm not getting this solution to work.

Comment: @Carl91: that would mean including Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting as a dependency.